# Get attributes of model in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, backbone.js

I have this model

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
   url: 'http://localhost/InterprisePOS/Product/loaditembycategory/Event Materials'
});

var onSuccess = function(){ alert("success"); };
```

And a collection

```
var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item
});
```

And the rest of my code is here:

```
var item = new Item();
var items = new Items();
item.fetch({ success: onSuccess });
alert(items.get("ItemCode"));
```

What I want is to simply get the attributes of the model. Now I have this on firebug. Also when I run it on the browser I get the alert **success** and the next alert is **undefined**.
[image]

This is the output:

```
{"ErrorMessage":null,"Items":[{"ErrorMessage":null,"CategoryCode":"Event Materials","ClassCode":null,"Components":null,"GroupCode":null,"ImageURL":null,"ItemCode":"ITEM-123","ItemDescription":"Old World Lamppost\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a","ItemName":"GET123","ItemType":null,"KitItem":null,"Matrix":null,"Prefix":null,"RetailPrice":107.990000,"SalesTaxCode":null,"UPCCode":null,"UnitMeasureCode":"EACH","UnitsInStock":0,"Value":null,"WholesalePrice":95.000000}]}
```

## NOTE

That is just one of the items it returns. I just posted on item so that it won't be that long.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are calling `get` on your collection ( see http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-get)

It seems what you really want is to iterate over the collection, and call get on each item

```
items.each(function(item) {
  item.get('ItemCode');
});
```

If not, please elaborate!

Additionally, if your model url responds with a list of models, you should be defining the url attribute in your Collection instead of your model.

```
var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item,
    url: 'http://localhost/InterprisePOS/Product/loaditembycategory/Event Materials'
});
```

And your response should be an array, with Items as array elements `[<item1>, <item2>, ...]`, rather than a JSON object with `{'Items': [<item1>, <item2>, ...] }`. If you don't want to modify the response, you will have to implement the `parse` function on your collection ( http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-parse ).

Also, as @chiborg mentions, you are calling `get` right after `fetch` (which will complete asynchronously), so there is no guarantee that your data will be available.

The proper solution here is to bind a 'refresh' listener on the collection.

```
items.on('refresh', function() {
  // now you have access to the updated collection
}, items);
```

Comment: sorry about the model part. I'm just experimenting on it since i noticed that the model Item doesn't get the attributes its empty. Also about the parse thing. I tried it but after i execute the code it doesn't retrieve the model. The model attribute of the collection is blank "[ ]" but i have the model: Item

Comment: What does your Model/Collection url (localhost/InterprisePOS...) return?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the model loading asynchonously - `item.get("ItemCode")` will only work after the model has been loaded with `fetch`. Try calling it in your onSuccess function.

Additionally, note that it won't help to initialize `Item` directly. What you are trying to do is get an element in the collection `Items` and then call `item.get("ItemCode")` on that element, like this:

```
function onSuccess() {
   alert('success')
   var item = items.get(13); // get item with id 13
   alert(item.get("ItemCode"));
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. But i throws an error stating that item from (alert(item.get())) is undefined.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not look at the result from the AJAX request. The Collection class of Backbone.js expects an array to be returned, not an object where the collection items are nested in it. Can you change what is returned on the server side, returning jsut the array that comes after "Items"?